# Proving convergence of $\int_0^\infty e^{-y} dy$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    xe^{-x^{2}}, & \text{if}\  x\geq0 \\
    0, & \text{if}\  x <0.  \\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation} 
$

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \;\mathrm{dμ} =  \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-y} dy = \frac{1}{2}$, but does this integral converge at all? How can I justify the change of variable in this improper integral?

---

I was given a hint that monotone converging sequence I can use is $f_n = xe^{-x^2} \cdot I_{[0,n]}$. Why is the following correct

$$\ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f \;\mathrm{dμ} = \lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0^\infty f_n  dx =\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0^n xe^{-x^{2}}  dx $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f_n(x)=xe^{-x^2} \cdot I_{[0,n]}(x)$$ (where $I_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise).

Note that $0\leq f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$ and that $f_n \to f$ pointwise. Now, use the monotone convergence theorem.